# How to maximize a window in background?

Tags: c#, winapi

I need to maximize a window in background, meaning without activating (focusing) it.
SetWindowPlacement function doesn't offer this..
Any ideas?

```
        WINDOWPLACEMENT wp = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
        GetWindowPlacement(hwnd, ref wp);

        wp.showCmd = 3;
        SetWindowPlacement(hwnd, ref wp);
```

Comment: u mean u want to maximise the windows form

Answer (score 1):

The best way I could find to do this was (VB sorry!);

```
longForeHWnd = GetForegroundWindow
Call ShowWindow(longBackHWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)
SetForegroundWindow (longForeHWnd)
```

This is only a work-around because the Background Window is (briefly) activated and so gets promoted up the Z-Order

Answer (score 1):

Try this using definitions from http://www.pinvoke.net:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT placement;
if (GetWindowPlacement(hWnd, out placement))
{
    if ((GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) & WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW) == 0)
    {
        var l = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
        SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, (l | WS_MAXIMIZE) & (~WS_MINIMIZE));
        var maxPos = placement.MaxPosition;
        SetWindowPos(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, maxPos.X, maxPos.Y, 0, 0, SetWindowPosFlags.AsynchronousWindowPosition | SetWindowPosFlags.DoNotActivate | SetWindowPosFlags.FrameChanged | SetWindowPosFlags.IgnoreResize | SetWindowPosFlags.IgnoreZOrder);
    }
}
```

The trick is to change the window state with SetWindowLong and redraw it with SetWindowPosFlags.FrameChanged. And in your case with SetWindowPosFlags.DoNotActivate.

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below code at the time of windows load

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

    }
```

This will maximise your window

Comment: I forgot to mention that i need to maximize other applications, not mine. Sorry.

Comment: what do u mean by other applications here??

Comment: i want to maximize other windows from my application. Using SetWindowPlacement API for example. Just without activating them (other windows).

Comment: to be honest please place your code, then only can help u much further

Comment: Sure. This will maximize an external app window, but also focus it (something i want to avoid):

            WINDOWPLACEMENT wp = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
            GetWindowPlacement(hwnd, ref wp);

            wp.showCmd = 3;
            SetWindowPlacement(hwnd, ref wp);