# Is It Possible To Change a Window's Size in The Background

Tags: windows, winapi, vb6

Related to, but a more general question than [How to Maximize a Window in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431009/how-to-maximize-a-window-in-background/19916608#19916608)

It is possible to Minimize, Restore, Move and Resize, and/or Maximize an Application Window using the ShowWindow() and SetWindowPos() API's

Using these has the disadvantage of changing the Active Window and Z-Order

Is it possible to make these changes in The Background, so that the changes only become noticable the next time it is Activated?

A soultion using  using API's or VB6 is preferred

"Rest assured that things will get worse, before they get a lot worse" - Anon.

Answer (score 3):

`SetWindowPos` doesn't have to change the z-order or activate the window.

- Use the `SWP_NOZORDER` flag to prevent the z-order from changing.
- Use the `SWP_NOOWNERZORDER` flag to prevent the window's owner's z-order from changing (if the window is owned)
- Use the `SWP_NOACTIVATE` flag to prevent the window from being activated.

These flags (and their values) are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).