# show application window in background while it is minimized in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to show the windows form in background while it is minimized in C#? It should not come to front or steal focus.

Comment: how are you going to show that if the form is Minimized...? think about what you are asking...

Comment: It should be just shown behind the current opened window (like you open 2 applications and the old application window is shown in background). I can show it without activation, but it always comes to front.

Comment: then call the BringToFront method of the new form that you're trying to show..

Comment: nope, BringToFront method will foreground the form. I do not want the form to be opened in foreground. This is the case: The form should be shown in its latest position and size (before minimized), but should not come to foreground, so the user can continue to work on the already opened window (another application)

Comment: If it is shown in background, then it is not minimized. You can replace the system command with your own that does something different, or create a new window that does not appear in the task bar that replicates the target window.

Comment: It would be very confusing... And the user just has to click on any other window to put your windows in background... The user should usually manage that by himself.

Answer (score 0):

The size of minimized windows gets set to zero. Therefore they are not visible.

Comment: This is not the case. I can get and keep the latest position and size before minimized.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19916608/3895126

C# version:

```
IntPtr longForeHWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
ShowWindow(form.Handle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
SetForegroundWindow(longForeHWnd);
```